# geometrical optics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, geometric-optics

I doing an experiment now.

My structure has 700nm periodicity.

The surface of the unit structure is sloped at 45 degrees from the normal incidence angle.

My laser is 500 nm.

I can expect there will be diffraction.

I wonder if the geometrical optics can be applicable for my case?

Or just I need to consider the diffraction?

I am asking this question because I have something that I can not explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by whether "geometrical optics can be applicable".

Geometric optics will work fine with a system with a grating like the one you mention, although you need to know the rules for calculating the directions and strengths of the transmitted / reflected rays. There are three main points to heed here:

1. In general, several separate rays will emerge from the incidence of one ray;
2. Their directions are governed by the [Bragg Resonance Condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bragg%27s_law).
3. Their relative strengths are governed by the actual shape of the periodic structure: these are related to the amplitudes of the components in the Fourier series describing the periodic index variation.

The reason that geometric optics works well here is that a ray stands for essentially a plane wave *i.e.* a wavefront that has minimal aberration over length scales that are typically much longer than the length scales in the grating you mention. Plane waves incident on a grating give rise to a set of plane waves, one for each integer solution in the Bragg resonance law.